# iPod is not Charging

Tags: hardware, charging, power-management, ipod-shuffle

When I connect my iPod shuffle to my computer it is not pulling up the profile that I can put music on normally it will pull up but it not pulling it up for me, and it won't charge it.

Another thing is I put Youtube music on the iPod shuffle and when I put is in my speaker that I have it works but when I put in headphones it doesn't work.

Can someone help me figure out why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Start with [force restarting your iPod Shuffle](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201605).  If that doesn't work there are three things you need to check:

1. The USB port is functional.  Try another device (any device is fine).  If it works, then you know your USB port is working.  If it's not, then you'll either need to use a different port (if available) or another computer
2. Check the cable.  The USB cable may be damaged and no longer allows for communication between the iPod and the USB port.  If possible, borrow one from a friend (preferred method), or you may have to purchase another one.
3. Verify that the Shuffle works.  If you can't get it to work (i.e. play music) then you definatley have a problem with the iPod.  If it will not communicate on the USB port, it's likely that the iPod USB interface has died.  It's unfortunate, but it does happen.